# SQL query running slowly

Tags: sql

I got this query working but it's really slow. I'm new to SQL so any help with Tuning would be appreciated.

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(LoweredUserName,'@domain.com','') as Name, 
    COUNT(LoweredUserName) as Numb
FROM 
    aspnet_Users 
JOIN 
    WarrantyRegistration ON CHARINDEX('Added by ' + aspnet_Users.LoweredUserName, 
WarrantyRegistration.Comment) > 0
GROUP BY
    aspnet_Users.LoweredUserName 
ORDER BY
    LoweredUserName ASC
```

Thanks

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Comment: @AndyLester the operations aren't SARGable so it doesn't matter what the indexes are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `WarrantyRegistration` table has an id for the user who added the registration, you should join on the IDs instead of doing the `CHARINDEX()` join.  If you can't do a foreign key join, you should seriously consider modifying your schema so that you can, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing a CROSS JOIN of `aspnet_Users`*  and *`WarrantyRegistration`, even though this may not be obvious, as the of every WarrantyRegistration record must b searched (again) for every aspnet_Users record.

Can you create an index on `WarrantyRegistration.Comment`* to support this query?